# How should I understand “the fact” and “quality” in definition of a word

Tags: meaning

I’m a foreign learner of English. I usually learn new words by looking at their dictionary definitions, and I often see “the fact of” and “quality of” in the definition of words. I get confused about what they mean.

In my native language, it just feels not right that these two words are used this way. As in this example, the definition of

> - **variance**: the fact or quality of being different, divergent, or inconsistent.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/variance)]

So how can I understand these two words in a natural way? In addition, is it best to learn all new words by remembering their definitions?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Language Learning.SE. But you only learn the different ways a word is used by reading a lot, listening to proficient speakers....

Comment: A more suitable example is << **timeliness**: noun [uncount] ...the (1) fact or (2) quality of happening at the best possible time or at the right time >> [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/timeliness)] //// (1) The timeliness of the arrival of the vaccine cannot be overstated // (2) The system may help severe-weather researchers improve the timeliness and accuracy of forecasting storms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a ***[fact](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01bDzQ9mgvgE8Q2Cy_jpu6fV7bAlQ%3A1608642470915&source=hp&ei=pu_hX8nFNaWEjLsPns2zwAo&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAX-H9tqo1KxL14tHUQTj-Cb_hS10r0y2Y&q=fact%20meaning&oq=fact%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DkBlj-H2CBJGgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjJsLCY1OHtAhUlAmMBHZ7mDKgQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)***?

> something that is known or proved to be true.

So *variance* refers to the ***truth*** that something is different etc.

What is ***[quality](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk021vQAR_Ht-nOFiG1MMeALbXgARbA%3A1608642479923&ei=r-_hX6v_N4HBgQar-KW4CQ&q=quality%20meaning&oq=quality%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBHOggIABAHEAoQHlCo6gxY_oANYO6CDWgAcAN4AIABqQGIAccHkgEDMC43mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjrktic1OHtAhWBYMAKHSt8CZcQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)***?

> a distinctive attribute or characteristic possessed by someone or something.

So *variance* refers to things which are ***characterised*** by divergence, difference, inconsistency.

It is clear that "fact" and "quality" point to different aspects of a concept.

At different stages of learning, definitions may sound complicated and abstract, but they are there for a reason and are usually spot on. The best way to learn a new phrase or word is by seeing or hearing it used in natural real communications.